# How to count number of levels (depth) in XML branch in perl XML::LibXML?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, libxml2, xml-libxml

I have a very simple problem. I want to find number of levels of an XML branch. Like:

```
<span>
 <span>
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline">
    <msup>
     <mn>34</mn>
     <mi>o</mi>
    </msup>
  </math>
  <span> </span>
 </span>
</span>
```

Should give a depth count of 5 when computed from the very first  (root) span tag.
I am using XML::Libxml.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It will be easier to help if we can fix your code.

Comment: @simbabque I tried to use the XPath's count(ancestor::*) methods (as in the node with maximum ancestor count is the branch depth). But I could not find a way to integrate them with XML::LibXML::Node. Probably XML::LibXML::XPathExpression might help but I was not able to get it working using that either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw( max );

sub max_depth {
   my ($ele) = @_;
   return 1 + max 0, map max_depth($_), $ele->findnodes('*');
}
```

The following accepts any kind of nodes instead of just element nodes (e.g. a document node):

```
use List::Util  qw( max );
use XML::LibXML qw( XML_ELEMENT_NODE );

sub max_depth {
   my ($node) = @_;
   my $base = $node->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE ? 1 : 0;
   return $base + max 0, map max_depth($_), $node->findnodes('*');
}
```